# How do use transloadit addStream() function in the NodeJS SDK?

Tags: node.js, transloadit

Trying out the transloadit api, the template works when I use the testing mode on the transloadit website, but when I try to use it in Node JS with the SDK I'm getting an error:

```
INVALID_FORM_DATA - https://api2.transloadit.com/assemblies - INVALID_FORM_DATA: The form contained bad data, which cannot be parsed.
```

The relevant code: (_asset.content) is a Buffer object

```js
async function getThumbnailUrl(_assetkey: string, _asset: I.FormFile): Promise<string> {
  let tOptions = {
    waitForCompletion: true,
    params: {
      template_id: process.env.THUMB_TRANSLOADIT_TEMPLATE,
    },
  };
  const stream = new Readable({
    read() {
      this.push(_asset.content);
      this.push(null);
    },
  });
  console.log(_asset.content);
  util.transloadit.addStream(_assetkey, stream);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    util.transloadit.createAssembly(tOptions, (err, status) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      console.log(status);
      //return status;
      resolve(status);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you also posted this question on the Transloadit forums - so in the case that anyone else runs into this problem you can find more information on this topic [here](https://community.transloadit.com/t/how-do-use-transloadit-addstream-function-in-the-nodejs-sdk/15357/6).

Here's a work-around that the OP found that may be useful:

> Just to provide some closure to this topic, I just tested my
> workaround (upload to s3, then use import s3 robot to grab the file)
> and got it to work with the nodejs sdk so i should be good using that.
>
> I have a suspicion the error I was getting was not to do with the
> transloadit api, but rather the form-data library for node js
> (https://github.com/form-data/form-data 1) and that’s somehow not
> inputting the form data in the way that the transloadit api is
> expecting.
>
> But as there aren’t alternatives to that library that I could find, I
> wasn’t really able to test that hypothesis.

The Transloadit core team also gave this response regarding the issue:

> It may try to set his streams to be Tus streams which would mean that
> they’re not uploaded as multipart/form data.
>
> In either case it seems like the error to his callback would be
> originating from the error out of _remoteJson
>
> These could be the problem areas
>
> https://github.com/transloadit/node-sdk/blob/master/src/TransloaditClient.js#L146
> https://github.com/transloadit/node-sdk/blob/master/src/TransloaditClient.js#L606
> https://github.com/transloadit/node-sdk/blob/master/src/TransloaditClient.js#L642
>
> It is also possible that the form-data library could be the source of
> the error
>
> To really test this further we’re going to need to try using the
> library he was using, make sure the output of it is good, and then
> debug the node-sdk to see where the logic failure is in it, or if the
> logic failure is on the API side.

Comment: Please add information related to answer first, then reference things.